# How to parse route feature weightings response with json?

Tags: c#, json, here-api

According to the API documentation (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html), route feature weightings are presented as a list of `RouteFeatureType: RouteFeatureWeightType` pairs.

If I want to set 2 or more weights in a `calculateroute` request, i.e.

```
"motorway:-2,boatFerry:-3
```

I get the relevant part of the resulting route in the `CalculateRouteResponseType` response:

```
\"feature\":
[{\"value\":\"boatFerry\",\"weight\":[\"Byte\",-3]},{\"value\":\"motorway\",\"weight\":[\"Byte\",-2]}]
```

It is clear that feature is a list of value-weight pairs. But how do the json objects representing each pair look like? I haven't been able to successfully parse the list of weightings.

So far I am down to

```
public enum RouteFeatureType
{
    TollRoad,
    motorway,
    boatFerry,
    railFerry,
    Tunnel,
    DirtRoad,
    Park
}
public class RouteFeatureWeight
{
    public RouteFeatureType value { get; set; }
    public List<string> weight { get; set; }
}
```

which gives me weight as a list of strings {"Byte", "-3"}.

What is the correct type instead of List so I obtain the correct RouteFeatureWeightType value, defined as

```
public enum RouteFeatureWeightType
{
    StrictExclude = -3,
    SoftExclude = -2,
    Avoid = -1,
    Normal = 0
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way

```
public class RouteFeatureWeight
{
   public RouteFeatureType value { get; set; }
   public List<dynamic> weight { get; set; }
   public RouteFeatureWeightType FeatureWeight { get; set; }
}
```

and after deserializing the response (using Newtonsoft.Json)

```
HereResponseType response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HereResponseType>(jsonResponse);
```

I convert the weight to the RouteFeatureWeightType enum type in each RouteFeatureWeight object

```
FeatureWeight = (RouteFeatureWeightType)weight[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to parse the response feature array as it matches the features you sent in the related request?

Otherwise, I do not believe you need to keep the response feature array as is. Therefore, you can have a parse method as follows (pseudo-code close to JavaScript that you can adapt):

```
parseFeatures(responseFeatureArray) {
  var features = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < responseFeatureArray.length; i++) {
    var featureObject = responseFeatureArray[i];
    var featureName = featureObject.get("value");
    var featureWeight = parseInt(featureObject.get("weight")[1]);
    features.push(new RouteFeatureWeight(featureName, featureWeight));
  }
  return features;
}
```

Let me know how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: The response tells what was actually done, which in theory can differ from the request. I parse the response simply using Newtonsoft.Json

HereResponseType response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HereResponseType>(resp);

The HereResponseType class defines the underlying object for the response. I have been able to define all fields of interest correctly except the "[\"Byte\",-3]", which seems to be a list. I do not wish to make a hack to parse the weights. I do not understand why the "Byte" part is there. Why not just -3 which can be mapped into the RouteFeatureWeightType enum?